# how to delete multiple data/rows in table model as well in my database

Tags: java, mysql, jtable

I have here a code that deletes only 1 row when I select one and hit the button.

```
    int row = tblRecords.getSelectedRow(); 
    DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)tblRecords.getModel();
    selected = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
    selected2 = model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();

    if(row>=0)
    {
      int confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to remove this Item?", "Confirm",2);
      if(confirm==0)
      {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String from = df.format(txtfrom.getDate());
                String to = df.format(txtto.getDate());
                model.removeRow(row);
                core.removeRec(selected,selected2);
                tblCompute.setModel(core.lateTotal(from,to));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");
            }
      }
    }
```

this is the function I used to delete in my database but can only delete 1 row

```
public void removeRec(String name, String date) throws Exception
   {
    Connect();
   int i =  st.executeUpdate("Delete from tbl_temp where holderName = '"+name+"' AND IODate='"+date+"'");
   }
```

Thank you!

Comment: You really should be [using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: You could put the whole thing into a loop, but that becomes a little inefficient, may using a batch update instead

Comment: ill make my row an array? then loop it? or any better idea?

Comment: I'd still do some research into who batch updates work personally.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need set `model.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION)`.
Then use `int[] selectedRows = table.getSelectedRows()` to get indexes of the selected rows. Call your delete procedure in cycle for each row. 
If you think there will be a lot of deletions in your table, it possible to rewrite delete query to call sql only ones: since you're checking value pairs (holder_name, io_date) there is no straight way to use prepared statement with `in (..)` clause, so you can construct query on the flight like this:

```
  StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
  b.append("Delete from tbl_temp where ");
  for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
      int row = selectedRows[i]; 
      String name = model.getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
      String date = model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
      b.append("(holderName = '" +name+"' AND IODate='"+date+"')");
      if (i < selectedRows.length - 1) {
         b.append(" OR ");  //omit the last OR 
      } 
  }
  st.executeUpdate(b.toString());
```

Comment: so I'll just pass the variable b in the removeRec function? like this    core.removeRec(b); and catch it with StringBuilder also?

Comment: and I'm haing an error at the setSelectionMode, it says that cannot find symbol